# How does a session work with SQL Alchemy with pool?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
engine = db.create_engine(self.url, convert_unicode=True, pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800, max_overflow=10)

connection = self.engine.connect()

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=True))
```

I initialize my session like this. And

```
def first():
    with Session() as session:
        second(session)

def second(session):
    session.add(obj)
    third(session)

def third(session):
    session.execute(query)
```

I use my session like this.
I think the pool is assigned one for each session. So, I think that the above code can work well when **pool_size=1, max_overflow=0**. But, when I set up like that It stuck and return Exception like.

```
descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'tuple'
```

Why is that? The pool is assigned more than one per session rather than one by one?
And when using session with **with**, Can do I careless **commit** and **rollback** when exception?

Comment: A scoped session will use the same session for each session() in the same thread (unless you provide a different scope function to  scoped_session)

Comment: @snakecharmerb So, it use only one pool? If then, why does pool_size=1, max_overflow=0 fail?

Comment: If you want to use just a single connection, use a [StaticPool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.StaticPool): `create_engine(..., poolclass=StaticPool, ...)`.